# EF 5. Code First DbContext Child objects not mapping on retrieving from DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this class;

```
[Table("tblRegions")]
public class Region : MasterEntity
{
      public string Code { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
      public Region ParentRegion { get; set; }
      public Country Country { get; set; }
      public RegionType RegionType { get; set; }
}
```

it turns out Region, Country RegionType fields are created as foreign key fields in DB and ID values saved correctly.

Problem is on retrieving a Region, ParentRegion, Country and RegionType are null yet in the db I see their Id values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to mark them as virtual.

```
 public virtual Region ParentRegion { get; set; }
 ...
```

This is how you let EF to create overridden properties within autogenerated proxy classes that lazy load your parent entities.

Comment: Alternatively you can eager load the data: `context.Regions.Include(t => t.Country).Include(t => t.ParentRegion).Include(t => t.RegionType)`.

Comment: marking them as virtual did not work. What worked was using 
currentEntity = _ctx.Set<Region>()
                    .Include("Country")
                    .Include("RegionType")